# What strategy to draw boids using shaders and sfml?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sfml, wsl-2

I want to implement a Boids simulation using C++ and SFML. Each boid is a triangle at a position (x,y), an angle, a radius of sight, and a tail showing its path history.

Drawing each boid using shapes in SFML resulted in poor performances, I eventually rewrote everything using vertex arrays (`sf::Lines` for the tail, `sf::Triangles` for the boids, and regular `CircleShapes` for the sight radius).

With this, I am limited to 10k boid before dropping below 60fps. I am now considering drawing each boid using shaders, I can then add other fancy glowing effects.

However, I am lacking the proper strategy to implement this. Let's say a boid is:

```
struct Boid {
    Vec2 position, speed;
    float angle;
    float sight_radius;
}
```

I tried to have a single full-screen texture and use fragment shader using uniforms array, but I am limited to 4k vec4 to pass the information of all boids. I also don't want to compute everything from the shader.

One solution could be to have one shader that receives varying such as:

- The position of the boid
- It's angle
- It's radius of sight

But I don't understand how to combine this together: sfml + vertex + fragment.

I asked chat GPT which recommends this:

> One way to approach this problem would be to use a geometry shader. A geometry shader is a type of shader that operates on whole primitives (triangles, lines, and points) and can output an arbitrary number of primitives, making it a good fit for your boids simulation.

I found an example, but my graphic card doesn't support geometry shaders.

Comment: Your graphics card does support geometry shaders.

Comment: @user253751 So my gldriver for WSL2 in Win11 does not support geometry shaders :(